# Converting Decimals to Fractions with JavaScript - Simplify & Improve

Tags: javascript

I wrote a simple script that converts a decimal to a mixed number, proper, or improper fraction depending on the inputed decimal.

It works but I think it could be improved as it hangs when large decimals are used. Please review and let me know how I could improve and simplify it. Thanks.

My script on JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/axulob/1/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
window.onload = function() {

    var factor; 

    // Finds the highest common factor of 2 numbers
    function highestCommonFactor() {
        for (factor = numerator; factor > 0; factor--) {
            if ((numerator % factor == 0) && (denominator % factor == 0)) {
                return factor;
            }
        }
    }

    // Enter a decimal to convert to a fraction
    var decimal = "1.75";

    // Split the decimal
    var decimalArray = decimal.split(".");

    var leftDecimalPart = decimalArray[0];
    var rightDecimalPart = decimalArray[1];

    // Save decimal part only for later use
    var decimalOnly = "0." + rightDecimalPart;

    // Find the decimal multiplier
    var multiplier = "1";

    for (var i = 0; i < rightDecimalPart.length; i++) {
        multiplier += "0";
    }

    // Create numerator by multiplying the multiplier and decimal part together
    var numerator = Number(multiplier) * Number(decimalOnly);

    var denominator = multiplier;

    // Find the highest common factor for the numerator and denominator
    highestCommonFactor();

    // Simplify the fraction by dividing the numerator and denominator by the factor
    var numerator = Number(numerator) / Number(factor);
    var denominator = Number(denominator) / Number(factor);

    // Output as a mixed number fraction (depending on input)
    var mixedNumber = leftDecimalPart + " " + numerator + "/" + denominator;

    // Output as a proper fraction or improper fraction (depending on input)
    var numerator = numerator + (leftDecimalPart * denominator);
    var fraction = numerator + "/" + denominator;

    // Display solution
    document.getElementById("divSolution").innerText = fraction;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="divSolution"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use an existing fraction library instead? Here's one https://github.com/LarryBattle/Ratio.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `highestCommonFactor` should take 2 integers as parameter instead of relying on the variable `numerator` and `denominator'. Also, you could find it using [Euclid'a algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm).
2. I am wrong is saying that this piece of code :

   ```
   var rightDecimalPart = decimalArray[1];
   // Save decimal part only for later use
   var decimalOnly = "0." + rightDecimalPart;
   // Find the decimal multiplier
   var multiplier = "1";
   for (var i = 0; i < rightDecimalPart.length; i++) {
       multiplier += "0";
   }
   // Create numerator by multiplying the multiplier and decimal part together
   var numerator = Number(multiplier) * Number(decimalOnly);
   ```

is here to transform a number such as `78924` in `0.78924` and then check that have to multiply it by 100000 to get an integer which is ... `78924`.

**Edit**
After a first cleanup, I get :

```
function highestCommonFactor(a,b) {
    if (b==0) return a;
    return highestCommonFactor(b,a%b);
}

var decimal = "1.75";
var decimalArray = decimal.split(".");
var leftDecimalPart = decimalArray[0];
var rightDecimalPart = decimalArray[1];

var denominator = "1";

for (var i = 0; i < rightDecimalPart.length; i++) {
    denominator += "0";
}
document.getElementById("debug").innerText = denominator;
var factor = highestCommonFactor(rightDecimalPart, denominator);

// Simplify the fraction by dividing the numerator and denominator by the factor
var denominator = Number(denominator) / Number(factor);
var numerator = (Number(rightDecimalPart) / Number(factor)) + (leftDecimalPart * denominator);

// Display solution as a proper fraction or improper fraction (depending on input)
document.getElementById("divSolution").innerText = numerator + "/" + denominator;
```

I'll try to go a step further.

**Edit 2**
After a rewriting of the calculation, here's what I got :

```
function highestCommonFactor(a,b) {
    if (b==0) return a;
    return highestCommonFactor(b,a%b);
}

var decimal = "1.75";
var decimalArray = decimal.split(".");
var leftDecimalPart = decimalArray[0]; // 1
var rightDecimalPart = decimalArray[1]; // 75

var numerator = leftDecimalPart + rightDecimalPart // 175
var denominator = Math.pow(10,rightDecimalPart.length); // 100
var factor = highestCommonFactor(numerator, denominator); // 25
denominator /= factor;
numerator /= factor;

document.getElementById("divSolution").innerText = numerator + "/" + denominator;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to go through my code. Could you explain how the function highestCommonFactor works?

Comment: I understand Euclid'a algorithm but I don't get how it's returning 2 values (return highestCommonFactor(b,a%b))? I assume it's multiplying (b) * ((a%b)).

Comment: The method highestCommonFactor takes 2 (integer) arguments and return 1 (integer) value. I used the formula from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm to write this recursive function.